# ReactJS - Validate Nested-IF/ELSE Statement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, filter, nested-loops

In my react app I'm using IF statement inside another IF statement to validate a condition that I want to get data filtered only from a specific column not from all.

Basically I'm using AntD table in which I'm displaying students data. In a table I do have few columns namely Age, Marks and Attendance. On each column(Age, Marks and Attendance) I'm applying a range filter with aim to fetch student(s) when applied search on a specific column i.e. either Age, Marks or on Attendance.

The problem I'm getting that my Nested-IF condition is not validating to true. Rest of code is working fine. I also tried to run code without Nested-IF(I mean with the simple IF/ELSE statement). That is also working fine.

I don't know what did I wrong or what I'm missing/skipping in my attempt.

**Help me to validate my Nested-IF/ELSE statement(s)**.

What I'm trying is:

```
const handleSearch = (firstInput, secondInput, dataIndex) => {
  setSearchStu(
    student.filter((obj) => {
      if (dataIndex === "age") {
        if (obj.age >= firstInput && obj.age <= secondInput) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (dataIndex === "marks") {
          if (obj.marks >= firstInput && obj.marks <= secondInput) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          if (dataIndex === "attendance") {
            if (obj.attendance >= firstInput && obj.attendance <= secondInput) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Where

`firstInput` is the 1st input field in a range filter

`secondInput` is the 2nd input field in a range filter

`dataIndex` is like a `key` to validate my 1st IF statement in Nested-IF case

Values `"age"`, `"marks"` and `"attendance"` are the defined values which are uniquely correspond to the each columns(Age, Marks and Attendance) in the table

and so on..

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You need to create unit test,( e.g. using jest) and debug with your data. As the function is too complicated, consider to split it into smaller function and test/debug each separately

Answer (score 0):

to simplfy your code, you can try this :

```
const handleSearch = (firstInput, secondInput, dataIndex) => {
  setSearchStu(
    student.filter((obj) => {
      if (dataIndex === "age") {
        return (obj.age >= firstInput && obj.age <= secondInput)
      } else {
        if (dataIndex === "marks") {
          return (obj.marks >= firstInput && obj.marks <= secondInput) 
        } else {
          if (dataIndex === "attendance") {
            return (obj.attendance >= firstInput && obj.attendance <= secondInput) 
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
};
```

or like this :

```
  switch(dataIndex){
    case "age" :
        return (obj.age >= firstInput && obj.age <= secondInput)
        break;
    case "marks" :
        return (obj.marks >= firstInput && obj.marks <= secondInput)
        break;
    case "attendance" :
        return (obj.attendance >= firstInput && obj.attendance <= secondInput)
        break;
    default : 
    return false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function does work given the right inputs and data - I made a sandbox on [replit](https://replit.com/@lizraeli/RotatingCorruptSecurity) to verify. Possibly there is an issue with the `student` data (consider renaming to `students`) or with the inputs to the function. Also, the function can be simplified to the following (see [replit](https://replit.com/@lizraeli/InsecureNavybluePacket) sandbox):

```js
const handleSearch = (firstInput, secondInput, dataIndex) => {
  return (
    student.filter((obj) => {
      if (["age", "marks", "attendance"].includes(dataIndex)) {
        return obj[dataIndex] >= firstInput && obj[dataIndex] <= secondInput
      }

      return false
    })
  );
};
```